# My wordpress website is deadly slow

Tags: php, performance, wordpress

We have a wordpress 3 installation on a fresh new dedicated server. Our website was working fine for about 1 year before on a very smaller VPS. After changing our hosting platform, we moved the website to our brand new windows server, but there were lots of problem with windows (long file names and ...). Finally, we bought a new linux dedicated machine (Quad core cpu with 4GiB of ram with cPanel and WHM (CentOS 6)).

On the new server, the website is DEADLY SLOW, page load is about 1 minute!

I've tried almost anything, from wordpress cache plugins (W3 Total Cache) to increase memory limit (php.ini and wp-config.php) and anything else I can think of...but nothing changed.

Could anyone help me please?

NOTE: the administration panel of wordpress is working fine. I am really mixed up :-/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out some of the following to see whats causing the issue. There are other benchmarking plugins available as well.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/benchmark/

Comment: benchmarks dont look bad: CPU Speed: 24,671 BogoWips (avg. 29,937 BogoWips) Network Transfer Speed: 4.61 Mbps (avg. 8.79 Mbps) Database Queries per Second: 2,398 Queries/Sec (avg. 1,330 Queries/Sec)

Comment: According to P3-profiler, it seems that the very high load time is because of theme! Total load time is 43.7 sec, and theme load time is 42.18 sec! Do you have any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: I've managed to fix it. Its looks like that some of theme files were infected with base64_decode like codes. removed the bad codes and it fixed.

Comment: Nice one, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your website for the best speed. There are thousands of plugins available for this.

You can use WP Rocket ( Paid one ) for speed optimization. Do minification of HTML,CSS, and Javascrip. Optimize images, compress images. Also serve your images in next-gen formats. Enable cache on your website.

It will skyrocket your website speed.

Comment: This is a very late and generic answer to a question the original poster indicated has been solved long ago using the other answer.